# How to Call Oracle Function Using Asp.net Web Api

Tags: asp.net, database, oracle, asp.net-web-api, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working on a project and i want to call a Oracle function using Asp.Net web API. Currently i am working with StoredProcedure and its working fine. I want that if My record submitted then it gives me some return value. My ASp.NEt web Api code and Oracle Function is as below:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < user.Count; i++)
            {

                var sParameter = new List<OracleParameter>();
                sParameter.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "@CRD_COD", Value = user[i].CRD_COD });
                sParameter.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "@ITM_COD", Value = user[i].ITM_COD });
                sParameter.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "@SRL_NUM", Value = user[i].SRL_NUM });
                sParameter.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "@UOM_ABR", Value = user[i].UOM_ABR });
                sParameter.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "@QTD_RTE", Value = user[i].QTD_RTE });
                sParameter.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "@QTY_PRC", Value = user[i].QTY_PRC });
                sParameter.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "@QTN_NUM", Value = user[i].QTN_NUM });
                sParameter.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "@PMT_FLG", Value = user[i].PMT_FLG });
                sParameter.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "@TAX_FLG", Value = user[i].TAX_FLG });
                sParameter.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "@DLV_FLG", Value = user[i].DLV_FLG });                    
                result = Convert.ToInt32(ADOManager.Instance.ExecuteNonQuery("NML.AddProduct", CommandType.Text, sParameter));                
           }
```

Here is the Oracle function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NML.AddProduct(V_CRD_COD In varchar2,
                                        V_ITM_COD In varchar2,
                                        V_SRL_NUM In varchar2,
                                        V_UOM_ABR IN varchar2,
                                        V_QTD_RTE IN varchar2,
                                        V_QTY_PRC In varchar2,
                                        V_QTN_NUM IN varchar2,
                                        V_PMT_FLG IN varchar2,
                                        V_TAX_FLG IN varchar2,
                                        V_DLV_FLG IN varchar2
                                        )
                                        RETURN NUMBER                                      
IS
```

BEGIN
IF SQL%FOUND THEN
  RETURN(1);
ELSE
RETURN(1);
END IF;
Exception When Others Then
          RETURN(1);
END;

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0):

Did you try executing the select statement wich calls the function?

.ExecuteScalar("SELECT NML.AddProduct(V_CRD_COD , V_ITM_COD , V_SRL_NUM , V_UOM_ABR , V_QTD_RTE , V_QTY_PRC , V_QTN_NUM , V_PMT_FLG , V_TAX_FLG , V_DLV_FLG ) FROM DUAL")

Comment: Select * from myfunction(customerid) from customer

Comment: sir i have to update the data i dont use select statement in my api. i have to call a function and have to store its return value in a variable

Comment: obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar("SELECT NML.AddProduct(V_CRD_COD ,
                                        V_ITM_COD ,
                                        V_SRL_NUM ,
                                        V_UOM_ABR ,
                                        V_QTD_RTE ,
                                        V_QTY_PRC ,
                                        V_QTN_NUM ,
                                        V_PMT_FLG ,
                                        V_TAX_FLG ,
                                        V_DLV_FLG 
                                        ) FROM DUAL")

Comment: MyFunction( is in  oracale database (TOAD)  as we call store procedure same i want to cal a function but dont know the syntax

Comment: Update NML.pgi_00_13 set UOM_ABR=V_UOM_ABR,
QTD_RTE=V_QTD_RTE,
QTY_PRC=V_QTY_PRC,
QTN_NUM=V_QTN_NUM,
PMT_FLG=V_PMT_FLG,
TAX_FLG=V_TAX_FLG,
DLV_FLG=V_DLV_FLG
Where CRD_COD=V_CRD_COD AND ITM_COD=V_ITM_COD AND SRL_NUM=V_SRL_NUM;

Comment: What is cmd here??

Comment: REplace "cmd" with "ADOManager.Instance.ExecuteNonQuery"